# IIS Url Rewrite Maps & Wildcard URLs

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module, rewritemap

Using IIS Url Rewrite, is it possible to match wildcard URLs using RewriteMaps? For example, I have the following rewrite rule:

```xml
<rule name="Disable access except for RewriteMap URLs" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <conditions>
        <add input="{Allowed Urls:{URL}}" pattern="1" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}" />
</rule>
```

which uses the following RewriteMap:

```xml
<rewriteMap name="Allowed Urls">
    <add key="/products" value="1" />
    <add key="/products/product-1" value="1" />
    <add key="/products/product-2" value="1" />
</rewriteMap>
```

I'd like to amend my RewriteMap to include a wildcard URL so I have one `add` element which matches the following URLs:

```xml
/products/id/1
/products/id/2
/products/id/3
/products/id/4
```

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the issue by adding an additional condition to my RewriteRule as follows:

```
<rule name="Disable access except for RewriteMap URLs" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <conditions>
        <add input="{Allowed Urls:{URL}}" pattern="1" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" negate="true" pattern="^/products/id/(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
    </conditions>
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}" />
</rule>
```